# Phase portrait of the simple pendulum. How much time does it take to get from one unstable equilibrium to the other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Consider a simple pendulum. I am trying to understand the phase portrait of its dynamics.

> I read that the "time" in which the dynamical system goes from the the unstable equilibrium $\theta = - \pi$ to $\theta = \pi$, is *infinite.* I do not understand how to *interpret,* let alone *formally prove* this fact; I read that it should follow from Cauchy's existence and uniqueness theorem.
>
> Can you explain to me both at the intuitive and formal level this fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't literally start at the first equilibrium point and expect to go somewhere else. If you start at an equilibrium point, then you are going to stay there forever, precisely because it's an equilibrium.

If you start somewhere on the trajectory connecting the two equilibria in the phase portrait, then as $t \to +\infty$ you are going to approach the second equilibrium, and if you trace the dynamics backwards in time, then as $t \to -\infty$ you approach the first equilibrium. So in that sense the trajectory in question “starts” at the first equilibrium, but there is no time $t_0$ such that at time you are precisely located there.

To prove that you can't reach the second equilibrium point $P$ in finite time (say at $t=t_0$), consider the solution which stays at $P$ for all $t$, and the solution which arrives at $P$ from somewhere else at time $t_0$ and then stays at $P$ for all $t \ge t_0$. Can you see how that would contradict uniqueness?

Comment: Well, to begin with, “equilibrium” literally *means* a state which is not changing. That is, either the pendulum is hanging straight down forever, or it's balancing straight up forever. If the pendulum is moving, it is (by definition) not in equilibrium.

Comment: Secondly, if you're going on the particular curve in the upper half of the phase portrait that connects the left green cross to the right green cross, then $E=1$, and you will get closer and closer to the right cross, but never reach it. There's another similar curve in the lower half going from right to left, and together these two arcs enclose a lens-shaped region. If $E<1$, then you are moving round and round on an ellipse-like curve *inside* that lens-shape (and that's the “red arrow” case, which corresponds to the pendulum swinging back and forth).

Comment: And if $E>1$, then you're going on a wave-like curve *outside* of the lens (that's the “violet arrow” case, when the pendulum keeps swinging round and round over the top). Those other curves do not pass through the equilibrium points. I think you might benefit from looking at a better picture than your hand-drawn diagram, like [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Phase-portrait-of-the-nonlinear-pendulum_fig2_230969993) for example.

Comment: Apart from terminology, I understand the case $E<1$ (swinging back and forth) and $E>1$ (swinging always in the same direction) and the corresponding curves in the phase portrait as you describe them. What is still baffling me is the case $E=1$. What I don't get is the physical interpretation. The other two physical interpretations are clear, but this one I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what the crosses mean. And an unstable equilibirium is a state which doesn't change (since it's an equilibrium), but which is such that if you start *near* it (not *at* it) you may be pushed away to some completely different part of the phase portrait (loosely speaking). And the case $E=1$ is when you give the pendulum just enough push to never swing back down but also to never swing over the top; it just keeps rising and getting ever closer to the vertical position (approaching it as $t \to \infty$, but never reaching it).

Comment: Now it's clear. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the pendulum equation (rescaled) is $\ddot\theta=-\sin(\theta)$, then around the upper equilibrium you can set $\theta = -\pi+u$ and get
$$
\ddot u=\sin(u)\approx u.
$$
The approximation has well-known solutions $u(t)=C\cosh(t)$ with the condition of starting at rest, $\dot u(0)=0$.

Pushing the pendulum (gently) out of its equilibrium means to position it some distance $\varepsilon$ away from it, $C=ε$. Let's say that the linear approximation of the sine is good for some distance $\Delta$, then the pendulum will leave that interval around the equilibrium at around
$$
t=\cosh^{-1}(Δ/ε)\approx \ln(2Δ/ε).
$$
So the smaller $ε$ the larger the time to move away from the equilibrium.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "swinging back and forth between the two equilibria". The equilibria are the north and south pole of the circle. If you start close to the north pole, you will pass the south pole with great speed and approach the north pole from the other side. What you describe are more the turning point where the velocity changes sign. These are not equilibria of the pendulum. The closer the turning points get to the north pole (with restart of the pendulum), the longer the period gets, approaching infinity.

Comment: They are the same point on the circle or the same position for the pendulum. So we established that if you put the pendulum into the ideal upright position, you could wait for all times and it would not move. So if you give it a push to some point slightly to the side, you would have to reach exactly the speed for $E=1$. This is practically impossible, you will give it either too much speed, $E>1$, or too little, §E<1$. If you are close enough, the pendulum will still "hesitate" visibly when it returns to the nearly upright position.

Comment: Now I got it, thank you.