# Mechanical system with asymptotic trajectory to the origin.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, ergodic-theory

I am trying to visualize some mechanical systems that have the origin in the phase plane ($q, \dot{q}$) as an unstable equilibrium. And to show that the equilibrium is unstable I want to show the existence of an asympotic trajectory to the origin ($q = 0, \dot{q} = 0$) when $t \rightarrow -\infty$.

My questions: Do you have any example of this? (maybe the unstable point of the pendulum, but I wasn't able to show an asymptotic trajectory to the origin).

In the case of mechanical systems with unstable equibrium, the system cannot be conservative, right? I was wondering if it can be possible to have an unstable equilibrium in a conservative system.

Answer (score 0):

Examples are

- an [upright pendulum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394788/phase-portrait-of-the-simple-pendulum-how-much-time-does-it-take-to-get-from-on) (on a rod, not on a string obviously), or balancing a rod on your nose,
- a roulette wheel, if it were just the bowl with the hill in the middle.